# getting 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. when try to add new fk in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Hi i am always getting 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. error on popup when i tring to add new fk in existed model using + in django admin .
i am using "admin_interface",and some other package releted to django-admin themes which are listed in installed apps ,is that reason that i am getting this error.

i try to pass "*" in ALLOWED_HOSTS in setting.py ,

when i am trying that process in google chrome browser it show as i share in image 1 but when i tring to do same with firefox it is shared in second image .

my setting.py file

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


SECRET_KEY = ''

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']




INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'grappelli',
    "admin_interface",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mdeditor',
    "colorfield",
    'drf_yasg',
    "rest_framework",
    'django_filters',
    "corsheaders",
    "storages",
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'authentication',
    'mails',
    'authors',
    'book_store',
    'institude_home_page',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vani_prakashan.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vani_prakashan.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
    #     'apps.authentication.backends.JWTAuthentication',
    # ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'authentication.backends.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 15,
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema'
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.User'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Base url to serve media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you please share the code of how to add data? @pysaundary

Comment: i am using admin panel , @PankajSavaliya

Comment: can you please try on another port via 
python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8081 and also assign ip in 
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['XX.XX.XX.XX'] instead of *

Comment: @PankajSavaliya getting same error  , on port 8081 and i also change allow host '*' to "127.0.0.1"

Answer (score 7):

Seems like a problem with iframe's Clickjacking Protection. The Django docs say:

> By default, the middleware will set the X-Frame-Options header to DENY for every outgoing HttpResponse. If you want any other value for this header instead, set the X_FRAME_OPTIONS setting.

Try this setting in order to allow iframes from the same ip addres as the main page:

```py
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

You can read more at: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses

Comment: thamkyou so much X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'  work ,can you only give me hint why this use ,definitely i will search it ,about it .thanks again

Comment: @pysaundary, the error is visible in the Firefox screenshot. I found for you this short explanation of a attack with a invisible iframe, and how the X-Frame-Options mitigates it: https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/clickjacking/

Comment: thanks again . i read Django docs and now i get what was wrong .